# How to set a interceptor for an action getting fired in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a really big form of about 50 components and I want to call a reducer that will set a flag to true whenever any changes have been made to the form i.e. whenever an action gets fired.

What I want is that the flag lets say `hasFormChanged`, initially false.  Whenever a single action gets called to change the form, it checks this flag and sets it to true if it isn't true already. Something like an interceptor for actions.

I am not sure how am I supposed to structure this. I really don't want to pass the flag setting reducer to all of my components. It would be a lot of repetitive code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [custom redux middleware](https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware#the-final-approach).
This is an example to a middleware (from the link above):

```js
const logger = store => next => action => {
  console.group(action.type)
  console.info('dispatching', action)
  let result = next(action)
  console.log('next state', store.getState())
  console.groupEnd()
  return result
}
```

You can call `store.dispatch()` with an action to set the flag you want.